# VBA How to programmatically use conditional formatting and have it apply to numbers only

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Using VBA and Excel
I have a dynamic range and I want to apply basic conditional formatting that turns the box green if there is a number greater than 0.8

some cells have text and not numbers and I do not want to format those cells.

Here is what I have so far but it doesn't work.

```
With RESPXL.xlsWS4.Range(RESPXL.xlsWS4.Cells(2, 7), RESPXL.xlsWS4.Cells(RECCNT, 19)).FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlGreater, "=IsNumber(xlCellValue)", "=0.8")
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Color = -11489280
    .StopIfTrue = False
    .Interior.Color = 13421823
    .Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
    .Interior.TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
End With
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a named range "RngTest" the following should do what you want

```
Sub CFTest()
    Dim Cond1 As FormatCondition
    Dim CFRange As Range: Set CFRange = Range("RngTest")
    Dim FirstCell As String: FirstCell = Replace(CFRange(1).Address, "$", "")

    With CFRange
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        Set Cond1 = .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER(" & FirstCell & ")," & FirstCell & ">0.8)")
    End With

    With Cond1
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Color = -11489280
        .StopIfTrue = False
        .Interior.Color = 13421823
        .Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
        .Interior.TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I set my range up but the code errors on on this line
  Dim FirstCell As String: FirstCell = Replace(Range("RngTest")(1).Address, "$", "")

Comment: oh I see, a named range in the excel sheet. I would have to programmatically create a named range.

Comment: That's just to have an example for the code; it can be any range you set prior to running the code, or you can set up a dynamic named range if you like...

Answer (score 1):

You should use a formula to determine your conditions like this.

```
.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND($A1>0.8, ISNUMBER($A1))"
```

Comment: IS there a way to do this but use xlCellValue instead of $A1 ?

Comment: You can only use xlExpression for your problem since it has different kind of comparisons (numbers and text). Tragamor's approach above is the only solution for your type of problems.